# How to know where flash coming from in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, single-page-application

I'm working on a legacy product, and have replaced all components directly dealing with Flash by JS. However Firefox still show me Flash plugin has been blocked every time application loads, which implies something still creating Flash (?)

How do I track every Flash resources called from the application ?

I used Chrome to inspect all of the resources tab, but haven't found anything related.

Comment: Any link to the problem page for a faster Answer? These recent **guess my mystery problem** questions are getting tiring now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to band together all the possibilities/paths we talked and added a few more:

- **Devtools > Flash:** Did you try Firefox's devtools by **F12** > **Network Tab** > **Flash** ? (Older versions may not have this tab, I'm using FFv53)
- **Iframe:** An `iframe` which has a Flash object can be the cause.
- **Object Tags:** You can search your codes for `object`, `embed` and even `param` tags.
- **swfObject**: If swfObject was used, you can search `swfobject` codes inside javascript codes.
- **AJAX:** I'm not sure about this. Can an AJAX call a `swf` object? You check `XHR` calls on load at devtools.
- **Page Info:** From menu, **Tools** > **Page Info** > **Media** > **Address** with a **Type** of *Embed* can show you if any one exists.
- **Flash download addon:** An addon can help you to find a Flash object. Here is an example addon: [Download Flash and Video](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/download-flash-and-video/)

Comment: Hmm interestingly I don't have that filter.

Comment: I'm using FF53... There are options: All, HTML, CSS, JS, XHR, Fonts... etc. and Flash

Comment: It showed blank. And I also tried filter by `swf`, `flash`. No luck

Comment: You can search your codes for `object`, `embed` and even `param` tags. If `swfobject` was used, you can search `swfobject` codes maybe...

Comment: I tried before with `object`, `embed`, `iframe` (inside it too). Also just tried param and `swfobject` but still nothing shown

Comment: Just making up, maybe some AJAX calls a swf object? Or even it's not a Flash at all, something like Silverlight? :) Maybe you can look at XHR calls on load at devtools.

Comment: Last thing in Firefox, **Tools** > **Page Info** > **Media** > **Address** with a **Type** of _Embed_ can show you if any one exists.

Comment: The Media suggestion is really good. Unfortunately couldn't find anything. And the addon showed nothing. I guess I'll move on.

Comment: Don't lose your hope, there must be a simpler answer than we thought!

Comment: It's the core lib that pulled in flash. I had to unminify it and remove flash code.

Comment: Wow, at last! Congrats :)